# The constructor SQLException(String) is undefined

Tags: java, jdbc, java-6

Using jdk1.6, there SQLexception(String s) is defined. But in my workspace it showing that SQLexception(String s) is undefined, please help.

[image: SQLexception(String s) is undefined]

Comment: Did you import it?

Comment: First, put the code and not screenshot. Second, check JRE version in your eclipse. Right click on project, properties and the Java. It's should JRE 1.6 or above

Comment: Don't throw a new one. Throw the one you caught.

Comment: yes, i already have imported java.sql.SQLException.

Comment: @yashpandey:it's jre1.6.0_45

Comment: @EJP and don't print the stack trace of the current one. This can make it look like you have multiple exceptions if you print it somewhere else as well.

Comment: In other words don't catch it at all. Catch-and-throw is an anti pattern.  @AndyTurner

Comment: May be closing the connection to early. Just a guess.

Comment: @EJP In this case, this is not the case. No such antipattern. But you can specify another rollback option per transaction.

Comment: Try saving your file and refreshing your project

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

this is because sqlexception is a checked exception , need to be wrapped with a try catch. if u are going to throw it again in the try catch it is better to throw it in the method. or throw a runtimeexception